# CodeIgniter multi-step signup

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session

I'm currently working on a web app that uses CodeIgniter, in specific, I'm building the signup forms.

This form consists out of 3 different steps, I'm just wondering what the best way would be in order to save information between 2 steps?
I only want to save all the information into the database once the final stap has been completed.

Should I just use native PHP session to do this? Or should I use CI flashdata?

Comment: `flashdata` would only last for one page.  Why not just use [CI sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)?

Comment: See this::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083014/multi-step-page-form-in-php-codeigniter

Comment: @AaronW. Possible too, I was looking for suggestions what the best way was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used hidden fields and sessions. I tend to save all the form values to a text file at the end of each stage. Then if something happens at any given stage I can choose what to do with the data saved in the text file.

For instance, if you wished you could capture an email address on the first page. If the form doesn't get completed (as in all stages were successfully completed), then you could send an email to the prospective user with a link to the signup form at the appropriate stage. The prospective user would not have to re-fill any of the fields they've filled in and you get a chance to recapture them as a user.

I tend to use the text file as a default way to save all the data from any stage of a multi-stage form. At the end of the form I can process the data into the DB and delete the text file. To catch partially complete signups I can write a script that is executed via a cronjob that runs every minute. I always save a timestamp in the data file representing the last time the file was updated. If the timestamp is more than X minutes old you run your didn't finish signup script on it or just delete it.

Saving data at each stage is simple. After the first stage you create the `$dataFile` with `$dataFile = file_put_contents(json_encode($data));` where `$data = array('timestamp'=>...) + $_POST;`. Each stage after the first I use `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($dataFile), TRUE) + $_POST;`, and `$data['timestamp'] = ...;`. Then use file_put_contents to save it back to the file. Obviously, you will need to track the $dataFile variable but this is easily done via hidden fields or session data.

The file will only be out there for X minutes before being processed and deleted but if you wish to have security on the text file during that short time frame then I'd suggest looking up a cipher or creating your own variation on the simple Ceasar's cipher. Use the cipher on the field names as well as the values.

Back in Dec I was working through the issue of multi-stage forms in the latest CodeIgniter for myself. I can't say this is a generally accepted best practice but the text file has worked well for me in the past. I posted some sample code for a multi-stage form here: [Multi-Stage Form Example](http://webtechnote.blogspot.com/2012/12/codeigniter-multi-stage-form-example.html).

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's a better process to save the array in a file as oppossed to saving in the database with something like serialize(array())?

Also, just to point out, CI has an encryption class which allows you to choose ciphers.

Comment: First I want to preface my comment by saying that my experience is entirely on my own projects using LAMP setups. I suppose that my bias towards text files over DBs can be traced back to a non-optimal LAMP setup. On my dev boxes I have found that too many DB connections (sometimes below 1000) can bring down my quad-core Ubuntu server. I have not found this to be true on my dedicated server but I've also done everything I can to avoid it. I have also found that saving data to DBs is slower than to a text file (again not tested on my dedicated server).

Comment: On my dedicated server I run primarily WordPress sites which can tie up quite a few MySQL connections. As a result of these experiences I control the number of DB connections I open with any tool. The easiest solution I've found is to use text files and post-process via cron job. A cronjob with 1 DB cxn can process a lot of text file in under a minute. Typically, I can handle user feedback from the text file and 1 min delay on it getting to the DB is not an issue.

Comment: One final note on DBs. I run several WordPress sites per server. Some DBs get corrupted while others, on the same server/hard drive, do not. I've never figured out why  but the text files can serve as a backup if need be. If you make daily backups of the DB and discover corruption at the end of the day, simply restore the backup and re-process the text files. To date I have not had any corruption issues with text file. That's my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the values to the next form where you can use hidden fields to store these values so that when you post the last form you have all the values and you can process them at one time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this process. How would you protect me from manipulating the hidden input values using a programme such as firebug and successfully completing to the next step? You'd need to validate the hidden form data was as submitted rendering this process pointless.

Comment: @Timmytjc Thanks for your feedback. I will keep this in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this case in my latest project and I used the session of Codeigniter to save the data submitted after validation in userdata session as array in the last step I send data to the DB