# how to save form information at different tabs into database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, tabs

I need to save data of a form into database..It is simple for me with a submit button..But now here I need to save data at its different stages..Or I'm having different tabs for each stage.. How could I save data.? I'm using a next button in order to navigate from one tab to other and at last there is a submit button..How it is possible to save data while clicking the next button.?

Here is my form:

```
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
      </div>
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
      </div>
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
      <?php
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $attributes=array('method'=>'post','id'=>'myform','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form');
      echo form_open("form_controller/insert",$attributes);
      ?>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3> Step 1</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input  type="text" required="required" class="form-control"  />
          </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3> Step 2</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Age</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" />
          </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3> Step 3</h3>
               <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Location</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" />
          </div>
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
      </div>
        </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: you can make use of session for this. It will be simple use and manipulate

Comment: how could I make use of session for this.?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of creating multi step forms. Here are some of the useful posts:

[How to Create a Multi-Step Form Using RhinoSlider](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/)

[session-based PHP-multistep-form with mvc-pattern](http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=1620)

[Multi step/page form in PHP & CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083014/multi-step-page-form-in-php-codeigniter)

[Multiple step form ragistration in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043520/multiple-step-form-ragistration-in-codeigniter)

[Multi-Step Forms and Data Submission in CodeIgniter](https://www.html5andbeyond.com/multi-step-forms-and-data-submission-in-codeigniter/)